# Extjs success is called twice and hence change event is also binded twice

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.define('js.custom.filterbar',{
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    alias: 'widget.FilterBar',
    onRender: function(){
        alert("in onrender filterbar");
        var me =this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        me.el.load({
            url: '/TRIFOLD/jsp/filterBar.jsp',
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("fail");
            },
            success: function(response){
                Ext.Function.defer(me.addStoreListeners, 50);
            }
            });
         },
        addStoreListeners : function(){
            Ext.get('store').on({
                change: function(){
                    alert("change");
                    var floorplanObj = Ext.create('js.custom.floorplan');
                    floorplanObj.getRequestParameters();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

In the code above the success of el.load is fired twice and hence my listeners are also binded twice. So onchange of the combobox the alert ("change") comes twice. Please tell what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please use the code-tag to format your code in a readable manner. Noone is going to read through that mess ;)

Comment: Why do you need to add listeners in that manner? Are you using ExtJs3 or 4? please tag

Comment: I am using Extjs 4. but the thing to be noted is success is called twice. How to stop it from firing twice?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem - while I don't have a patch-type solution you can apply to the Ext classes, I do have a (hacky) solution that works for me (ExtJS 4.0.7, btw)

```
Ext.get('someEl').load({
    url: '/some/content.php',
    success: function (resultOrEvent){
        if(resultOrEvent.hasOwnProperty('request'))
        {
           // Do your post-load stuff here
        }
    }
});
```

I have no idea why this is firing twice, but it's been quite annoying. What I'm seeing in the console for 'resultOrEvent' is just that - the first time I get the expected request object back, the second time I get an object of type `Ext.ElementLoader`

I'm looking into a fix for this (if it's a problem), and I'll be sure to post back if I find one.